# Transform checkboxes (multiple selections) to radio buttons or checkbox with single selection?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following list of checkboxes. The way the list is output it allows the user to select more than one value. However, I need the user to be only allowed to select one single value from the list of checkboxes below.

Is it possible to somehow achieve this with jQuery? It would also be okay to change the list to radio buttons, select list or anything else that might help.

Unfortunately I have no access to the generating function, so I cannot change the output.

Thanks in advance

```
<form class="ajax-form" id="user-register" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="(...)">

(...)

<div id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-berlin-wrapper" class="form-item form-option">
    <label for="edit-notifications-custom-custom-berlin" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-berlin" name="notifications_custom[custom_berlin]"> Berlin</label>
</div>

<div id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-hamburg-wrapper" class="form-item form-option">
    <label for="edit-notifications-custom-custom-hamburg" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-hamburg" name="notifications_custom[custom_hamburg]"> Hamburg</label>
</div>

<div id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-frankfurt-am-main-wrapper" class="form-item form-option">
    <label for="edit-notifications-custom-custom-frankfurt-am-main" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-frankfurt-am-main" name="notifications_custom[custom_frankfurt-am-main]"> Frankfurt am Main</label>
</div>

<div id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-duesseldorf-wrapper" class="form-item form-option">
    <label for="edit-notifications-custom-custom-duesseldorf" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-duesseldorf" name="notifications_custom[custom_duesseldorf]"> Düsseldorf</label>
</div>

<div id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-bielefeld-wrapper" class="form-item form-option">
    <label for="edit-notifications-custom-custom-bielefeld" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-bielefeld" name="notifications_custom[custom_bielefeld]"> Bielefeld</label>
</div>

<div id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-muenchen-wrapper" class="form-item form-option">
    <label for="edit-notifications-custom-custom-muenchen" class="option"><input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" value="1" id="edit-notifications-custom-custom-muenchen" name="notifications_custom[custom_muenchen]"> München</label>
</div>

(...)
```

asdasd

Comment: If you are able to, radio buttons are the way to go. There is no need to add complicated client-side code to achieve something that is natively available in HTML.

Comment: I agree, but as I said I cannot change this before it is output.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.form-checkbox').bind('click', function() {
    $('.form-checkbox').not(this).attr('checked', false);
});
```

EDITED to optimize performance.

Comment: You could simplify this to `$('.form-checkbox').not(this).attr('checked', false')`, which would significantly increase performance.  [attr() is a lot slower than each() in this case](http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-each), however.

Comment: Thanks! Using .each has become almost mechanical to me. heh.

Comment: What a neat solution! Thx

Comment: This worked for me as well. I know its old but does the trick. I just had to make my checkboxes look like radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to do this would be to change the type in the original HTML.  If you can't do this, however, you could do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.form-checkbox').change(function(){
        $('input.form-checkbox').not(this).each(function(idx, el){
            el.checked = false;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this code change the process code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.form-checkbox').each(function(){
       var self=$(this);
       $(this).replaceWith(
           $('<input type="radio" />').
               attr("value",self.attr("name")).
               attr("name","notifications_custom").
               attr("id",self.attr("id")).
               addClass("form-radio")
       );
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('[type=checkbox]').attr('type','radio');
```

Comment: You can't change the type of an input once it's added to the DOM.

Comment: maybe using .insertAfter to insert a radio with same details after it and then remove the original